# How can I sync my Contacts with Gmail if the stock firmware of my phone doesn't provide this feature?

Tags: contacts, sync, go-contacts

Am using a Grandstream GXP2200 Android deskphone that has a customized version of 2.3.5 on it. They have replaced the native contacts app with a custom one that doesn't sync with Gmail. I have replaced this with GO Contacts, but had to manually import contacts into GO. The phone has Google Play on it and I can install apps readily. How can I sync my contacts?

Comment: "Is there an app for X?" questions are off-topic. Please rephrase your question to ask for a solution. E.g. "How can I sync my Contacts with Gmail if the stock firmware of my phone doesn't provide this feature?"

Comment: I edited it per your suggestion. Can you reopen it?